# DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION caused ONLY by Halo 5: Forge

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I keep getting DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION BSOD's but only when playing Halo 5 (usually when loading into a level), never any other time. I have an i5 3570k, GTX 1060 on the latest drivers, and 12GB of RAM. I never get BSOD's playing any other game. Also should note that I'm on the latest build, 1607 (14393.105)

[Here's my minidump from the crash](https://my.mixtape.moe/jbgiun.dmp)

[image]

Comment: Take a look: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/dpc_watchdog_violation-blue-screen-in-windows-10

Comment: I don't have a SATA AHCI controller

Comment: @343N - Yes; Yes you do based on the hardware (your CPU) you are using that has to be the case.  Have you used windbg to determine the cause of the crash?  If you truely believe your not using a AHCI controller, provided the deveice manger inforation, so we understand what you are using.

Comment: no, I haven't, I'm not really sure how and it's pretty confusing, can't figure it out. And when I say I don't have it, I mean it's not there in Device Manager.. http://a.pomf.cat/dzkmck.png

Comment: @343N - There is an existing answer on this website that explains how to use windbg.  You are using SATA drivers?  Are you willing to switch to AHCI mode if that will solve the problem?

Comment: I think I tried switching to AHCI once and it requires a new OS install doesn't it? I'd rather not, if it's just to solve this one blue screen. I'll look at the website and use WinDBG and report back, thanks

Comment: Here, http://pastebin.com/XGJ0d440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Analyzing the dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows the nVIDIA driver as cause:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, A single DPC or ISR exceeded its time allotment. The offending
    component can usually be identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000501, The DPC time count (in ticks).
Arg3: 0000000000000500, The DPC time allotment (in ticks).
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.103 (rs1_release_inmarket.160819-1924)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name

SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1403

BIOS_DATE:  08/06/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  P8B75-M LX

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev X.0x

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 501

BUGCHECK_P3: 500

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  SINGLE_DPC_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: d40

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3a,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1B'00000000 (cache) 1B'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800677f6b0e to fffff800677d90d0

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!KeClockInterruptNotify
03 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt
04 nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
05 nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw
06 nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw
07 nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire
08 nt!KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc
09 nvlddmkm


IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release_inmarket

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.14393.103


0: kd> lmvm nvlddmkm
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff80e`71240000 fffff80e`7201d000   nvlddmkm T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Aug 25 22:31:18 2016
```

The 1060 is a new card, so the driver may still have issues and bugs. Report it to [nVIDIA in their forums](https://forums.geforce.com/default/board/33/geforce-drivers/).